# Is there any way to get the view object in views-view-grid-page.tpl.php

Tags: views, theming

Here is the views-view-grid-page.tpl.php code:

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Default simple view template to display a rows in a grid.
 *
 * - $rows contains a nested array of rows. Each row contains an array of
 *   columns.
 *
 * @ingroup views_templates
 */
?>
<?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
  <h3><?php print $title; ?></h3>
<?php endif; ?>
<table class="<?php print $class; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <?php if (!empty($caption)) : ?>
    <caption><?php print $caption; ?></caption>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row_number => $columns): ?>
      <tr <?php if ($row_classes[$row_number]) { print 'class="' . $row_classes[$row_number] .'"';  } ?>>
        <?php foreach ($columns as $column_number => $item): ?>
          <td <?php if ($column_classes[$row_number][$column_number]) { print 'class="' . $column_classes[$row_number][$column_number] .'"';  } ?>>
            <?php print $item; ?>
          </td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to do some modifications on this code and in these modifications I have to get the loaded view object and it's properties. Is there anyway to do this?

Unfortunately `dsm($rows)` doesn't give me the object it only display set of html tags.

Comment: Did you check `dsm($views);`? I thinks `$views` variable can be access in all views template files.

Comment: The `$view` object is available in every views template file.